# Logical error while using realloc() function

Tags: c, realloc

I am using dynamic memory allocation in C for a simple problem that I am trying to solve. It involves taking user input for the elements of 2 arrays. I was thinking that I will initialise the array to a large size and use realloc to reduce the size once the input has been completed. ?below is the code for same:

```
void arrayop()
{
    int val, i=0;
    int *arr1 = (int*) calloc(100,sizeof(int));
    int *arr2 = (int*) calloc(100,sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter first array:(-1 to stop)\n");
    while(val!=-1)
    {
        if(val != -1)
        {
            scanf("%d",&val);
            *(arr1 + i) = val;
            i++;
        }
    }
    //printf("\t%d\n",i);

    arr1 = (int*)realloc(arr1,(i));
    //printf("\t%d\n",(sizeof(arr1)));
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf("%d ",*(arr1 + j));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

However, realloc() is somehow overwriting already entered elements and filling them with garbage value. Can anyone give me any insight as to why this is happening, or where I am wrong?
[image: Output showing the array with garbage value]

Comment: `realloc(arr1 * sizoef(int), ...`

Comment: You want `realloc(arr, i*sizeof(int))`.

Comment: Also, don't write `*(a + i)`.  Just write `a[i]`.  Don't fight the language.

Comment: You can also get rid of the `if (val != -1)` test inside the loop.  That statement can never be reach if that test is false (look at the `while` condition directly above it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`realloc` expects the allocation size, but you're telling it how many `int`s you want. When you call it like this:

```
arr1 = (int*)realloc(arr1,(i));
```

`i` holds the number of `int`s that you want to allocate space for, but the actual size needed for the allocation is `i * sizeof(int)`, so to fix it you need:

```
arr1 = realloc(arr1, sizeof(int) * i);
```

Or, even better:

```
arr1 = realloc(arr1, sizeof(*arr1) * i);
```

The second variant will work even if you change the type of `arr1` from `int *` to, say, `short *`.

You may also want to check the pointer returned by `realloc` and make sure the allocation succeeded. Note that if `realloc` fails, `arr1` won't be freed and you'll end up leaking it. A better approach is:

```
int *temp = realloc(arr1, sizeof(*arr1) * i);
if (temp == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "realloc failed\n");
    free(arr1);
    return;
}
arr1 = temp;
```

While we're at it, don't cast the result of `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
.